# difference between :first and :first-child not clear

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am having a ul li list

```
<ul>
<li>Parent
    <ul>
       <li>
          child1
       </li>
       <li>
          child2  
       </li>

    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

and i am trying to use a selector `jQuery('ul li:first')` and `jQuery('ul li:first-child')` both giving the same result this makes me confused about the difference between the two is there a example which clarifies the difference between two selectors

Comment: I bet it's not really giving you the same result.

Comment: yeah you may be write i am definetly doing something wrong here :-)

Comment: It may appear to give the same result if you did something like `jQuery('ul li:first-child').html()`, which will only display the HTML of the *first* match, even though there are two.

Comment: This question is pretty useless, since you can find the answer in the first sentences in the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) API spesification.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**From Official Docs:**

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent
>   to :eq(0). It could also be written as
>   :lt(1). While this matches only a
>   single element, :first-child  can
>   match more than one: One for each
>   parent.

While `:first` matches only a single element, the `:first-child` selector can match more than one: one for each parent. This is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`.

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

**Update:**

Here is an example using `:first-child`:

http://jsbin.com/olugu

You can view its soruce and edit yourself. If you replace `:first-child` with `:first`, it will only highlight the first word there. This is what is defined for them.

And here is example using `:first`:

http://jsbin.com/olugu/2

Comment: thanks sarfraj, can you please modify my example where first-child will yield a result different from :first. sorry for not properly following what you mentioned

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes, but not always, the result is (and should) be the same.

Given your HTML:

```
jQuery('ul li:first').length; // Returns 1

jQuery('ul li:first-child').length; // Returns 2
```

So, you can see, that the first line is returning only the first `li` element.

The second line is returning both `li` elements that are a `first-child` of their parent.

`:first` returns the first in a matched set.

`:first-child` returns elements that are the first child element of their parent.

The first `li` element in your HTML is also a first child, although using `:first-child` is yielding more results when you test the `length` property.

You could actually combine the two selectors if you only want the first match that is a first child.

```
jQuery('ul li:first-child:first').length; // Returns one
```

Answer (score 6):

From your example:

```
$('ul li'); // Returns all 3 li's
// <li> Parent ... </li>
// <li> child1 </li>
// <li> child2 </li>

$('ul li:first'); // Returns the first li of all matching li's from above
// <li> Parent ... </li>
```

Assuming we have all three results from the first selector `$("ul li")`, then the `:first-child` will filter out any element from that list that is not the first child of it's parent. In this case, `<li> child2 </li>` gets filtered out because it was the 2nd child of a `<ul>`.

```
$('ul li:first-child')​;​ // Returns all li's that are the first child of any ul
// <li> Parent .. </li>
// <li> child1 </li>
```

Also, for the first-child selector, the element has to be the very first child in the DOM, and not in the jQuery result set. For example, with the given structure:

```
<div>
    <h1>First</h1>
    <span>Second</span>
    <span>Third</span>
</div>
```

the query below will yield 0 results as `<span>` is not the first-child of div.

```
$("div span:first-child")
```

A good way to understand `first-child` would be to think of it as a filter that will filter out any element in the current result set, if it is not the very first child of its parent.

Comment: +1 for a wonderful explanation; specially the div span example this makes the concept very clear thanks a lot for taking time for it

Answer (score 2):

This is an illustration of what `$("prev next:first")` and `$("prev next:first-child")` would actually select:

```
<prev>
    <next>...</next> // <- both `:first` & `:first-child`
    <next>...</next>
    <next>...</next>
</prev>
<prev>
    <next>...</next> // <- only `:first-child` (NOT `:first`)
    <next>...</next>
    <next>...</next>
</prev>
```

`:first` returns only the first result, while `:first-child` returns one result per parent (if any).

Answer (score 0):

when we use `:first` it selects the first child element of the first specified element  and when we use `:first-child` it select all first child element of the specified element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnfirst").click(function(){
        $("ul li:first").hide();
    });
    $("#btnfirstChild").click(function(){
        $("ul li:first-child").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p>List 1:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Book</li>
  <li>pen</li>
  <li>pencil</li>
</ul>

<p>List 2:</p>
<ul>
   <li>Book</li>
   <li>pen</li>
   <li>pencil</li>
</ul>

<button Id="btnfirst">:first</button>
<button Id="btnfirstChild">:first-child</button>
</body>
</html>
```