# Simple jQuery based ascii animation crashes after adding colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to create a simple ascii animation that is not based on textarea. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Simple Animation</title>

<style type="text/css">

  body { white-space: pre; font: 16px monospace; }
  #animation { position: relative; width: 500px; height: 332px; }
  #animation .image { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }

  .red { color: #ee0000; }

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
  $('#animation div.image:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#animation :first-child').hide()
      .next('div.image').show()
      .end().appendTo('#animation');}, 
    500);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="animation">
<div class="image">
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
</div>

<div class="image">
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
</div>

<div class="image">
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

It works exactly the way i wanted. However, the problem starts when I'm trying to add some colors. If i change the first line of X'es to

```
<span class="red">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
```

The animation is getting crazy, some lines are showing up, some aren't, some of them are in colors, some are still black etc. It's getting even worse when I'm trying to add some more colors.

My question is: why is this happening and how to fix it? I'm not a javascript professional, I suspect it may be a problem with selectors, however i wasn't able to fix it myself. Thanks!

Comment: If you could make a http://jsfiddle.net about this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is the use of `:first-child` instead of `:first`; with elements without children it works, if they have children will break your code.

While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent.

So this:

```
$('#animation :first-child').hide()
```

will select two elements instead of one (the two nested children) and your code break up its animation; try putting a console.log in your setInterval and you'll see the difference.

From docs:

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be
>   written as :lt(1). While this matches only a single element,
>   :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/VXaNB/

Linked question: [difference between :first and :first-child not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946205/difference-between-first-and-first-child-not-clear)

Answer (score 0):

In line `$('#animation :first-child').hide()`, change selector `:first-child` to `:first` and it should work. ;)

Otherwise in the long term you will not select the elements you want!

Comment: Never heard of **css** selector **first**, sure you're not mixing it with this http://api.jquery.com/first/?

Comment: @Christian it's a jQuery emulator pseudo-selector

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* answer is to use `#animation > :first-child`.

This ensures that the only elements you get are the direct descendants of `#animation`, and is also a legal CSS3 selector that doesn't depend on the `:first` jQuery extension, therefore more efficient and more portable.