# How to set style class for a tr when table id is known?

Tags: jquery, html, css

okay. I am a novice in jquery. I have numerous html tables in my application used for different purposes in jsp's. I would like to set a css style class using jquery while hovering on a row. At present I have below code.

```
$("tr").not(':first').hover(
function () {
    $(this).addClass("rowHighlighter");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("rowHighlighter");
});
```

But it sets the class to all tables and I would like to add a condition that this class should be applied for rows of table with certain id. I would appreate any inputs/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Change `$("tr")` to `$("#table1 tr, #table2 tr, ...")`?

Comment: Is there one specific id you know in advance you need to filter for, or are they dynamic (and possibly more than one on the page)?

Comment: Its just one specific id. I use this id whenever I want to show some tabular information.

Comment: This snippet solved my problem. And I used first-child from Sam's answer. Thank you j08691 and sam-battat !

    $("#cops_info_table tr").not(":first-child").hover(
            function () {
            $(this).addClass("rowHighlighter");
            },
            function () {
            $(this).removeClass("rowHighlighter");
            });
        });

Comment: Not sure why it does not allow me to format the code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("tr").hover(
function () {
    if(!$(this).is(":first-child")) $(this).addClass("rowHighlighter");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("rowHighlighter");
});
```

OR simply:

```
$("tr").not(":first-child").hover(
function () {
    $(this).addClass("rowHighlighter");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("rowHighlighter");
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6je0cq7f/

Comment: How is this any different than what the OP has?

Comment: This checks is the tr is first child, then adds the class

Comment: And that's different from `.not(':first')` how?

Comment: yes, it is different and this case first-child only works. to know the difference look at this or go over the jquery documentation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946205/difference-between-first-and-first-child-not-clear

Comment: @bkrish Please mark this as an answer if it works (I know it does, but people still mark it down :( )

Comment: Thank you! I hope people read and look at examples before they vote down