# Select items from different lists at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the HTML I got to do a button click event to control selected items in more than one list.

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    var $next = $('.section.selected').removeClass('selected').next('.section')
    if ($next.length) {
        $next.addClass('selected'); 
    }
    else {
        $(".section:first").addClass('selected');
    }
});

//On click I select next div with same class and remove selected from previous.
//How to loop? After 3 is selected, I want it to go to one again.
```

```css
.selected { background:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all">
  <div class="section selected">ONE</div>
  <div class="section">TWO</div>
  <div class="section">THREE</div>
</div>
<div id="all">
  <div class="section selected">ONE</div>
  <div class="section">TWO</div>
  <div class="section">THREE</div>
</div>
<br />
<a href="javascript:;" id="button">CLICK</a>
```

However, because the items are using the same class name, at the end, the script can't decide which one is first / last item.

Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Ah, I changed them to class, forgot to save, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the items, use Queries like `first-child`, `last-child` and so on.

For more detals, Check [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @A7bert the link I provided contains all jQuery selectors. Take time to read it. you may find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead `$(".section:first-child").addClass('selected')` in your `else` condition

Comment: Thank you... I can't figure out what is difference... But thanks for your fast answer.

Comment: Hi, you can find the difference here,
[jQuery first vs first-child](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2946217/5648904)